# Column Store Indices versus Dimensional Tables

Tags: sql-server, dimensional-modeling, columnstore

I have a Data Warehouse and want to think ahead one year when I may get a database update allowing me to use column store indices.

My dimensional tables are mostly junk dimensions containing columns that categorize the data in the fact tables. I use those dimensional tables mainly to compress the data (x10 roughly) and also get faster range searches.

Are those columns in my dimensional tables good candidates to be moved back into the fact table as part of a column store index?